# Image is not storing after running the screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am using pycharm to capture the screenshot of the website and use to store in the folder. 
The code is running and giving the message as exit with 0.

Windows 10, pycharm, google chrome browser, selenium and python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\test\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/")

driver.maximize_window()

#driver.save_screenshot("D:\test\one.jpg")

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("D:\test\two.png")

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by escaping the backslashes:

```
driver.save_screenshot("D:\\test\\one.jpg")
```